# get data for current product from custom table magento

Tags: magento

I have created custom table and model, I can access all data by this model using this code

```
$model = Mage::getModel('groupprice/groupprice');
$data = $model->getCollection()->getData();
print_r($data);
```

I just want to filter data only for current product, foreign key in custom table for product is product_id .

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$productId = 1;//change to your product id
$collection = Mage::getModel('groupprice/groupprice')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    //do something with $item
    //for example print_r($item) to see all it's data
}
```